# Capture ASP output for monitoring

Tags: asp.net, vb6, web-scraping

How do I Capture ASP.NET output and then store it as temp memory so that I can use them in an application to do comparison.

example.

there's this site which has ASP output. Sorry I do not have server access, what I can do is view the output.

The site by the way is a monitor for all users logged in and in which ever channel.

output e.g.

---

```
Channel 1

Username              logged in (0 / 1)
Username 1                    1
John Smith                    1
George B                      0

Channel 2

Username              logged in (0 / 1)
Username 1                    1
John Smith                    0
George B                      0
```

---

what I wanted to do is to capture this output and then show them this way.

```
Username                    Channel 1             Channel 2            Total
Username 1                      1                     1                  2
John Smith                      1                     0                  1
George B                        0                     0                  0
```

---

I dont knw where to start.

Comment: What platform will you be capturing the data with?

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution would be to screen-scrape the web page, load the data into an array, and sum on output.

Once you have chosen the platform you want to develop on, come back here and ask more specific questions as you run into issues.

Comment: Can you please guide me where to start? I am sorry I still in the learning process. I wanted this to be my 1st project

Comment: If you are just learning, then start with a modern technology, not VB6. If you know VB already, you could download the free Microsoft Visual Basic 2008 Express Edition (http://www.microsoft.com/express/Windows/).

Comment: I see.. what can u suggest as an easier way than VB? Thanks very much for helping out.